# Drive CW VCSEL Array

Tags: power-supply, laser-driver, vcsel

I want to build an array from VCSELS which I want to be able to turn on and off individually. My first thought was to just use a microcontroller, an external power source and MOSFETs to turn each VCSEL on and off individually. I'm not too keen on the electronics part here, how important is it to have dedicated laser diode drivers for the VCSELs or can I also use a regular constant current power source?

Comment: VCSELs are a bit more forgiving than edge-emitting laser diodes because they tend to have higher series resistance and it's not so easy to suddenly be driving them with 10x the current you meant to. But they're still fairly fussy about ESD. It'll depend a lot on exactly which device you are using.

Comment: I'm planning on using the Laser Components VD-0850I-004W-1C-2A0. The datasheet is available online. For power supply, I'd go with a MeanWell model that fits the specs.